# Font Awesome With ADF

Tags: css, font-awesome, oracle-adf

### I cannot use font-awesome with Oracle ADF 12c.

i found many tutorials and i try to do it but i cannot success like this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hk5giHC1hJM

this URLs could not readable in JSF Page.

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0');
 src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0') format('embedded-opentype'),
   url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0') format('woff2'),
   url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0') format('woff'),
   url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0') format('truetype'),
   url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
```

so i want example if any one do it before ?

**Thanks ...**

Answer (score 0):

Are you using JDeveloper 12 or an older version?
This won't work with an older version.
The steps are listed here:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/leveraging-icon-fonts-font-awesome-in-oracle-adf-500-new-icons-for-your-app

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply
I try this before by jdeveloper on 12c 2.1.3 but also do not work
If you have an application for example, I'll be thankful to you